# Give access to a different process for a file system

Tags: android, init, partition, fs, init.d

Lets say I am mounting a partition to a filesystem as below for process wiht uid 1023,i want to give access to that file system for a different process with a different uid,how do I do that?

```
mount vfat /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/partition /filesystem ro shortname=lower,uid=1023,gid=1023,dmask=227,fmask=337
```